# Looking for algorithms context-aware to solve a Bicycle Routing Problem

Tags: algorithms, routing

I am conducting a study has the general objective to build a route recommendation system for bicycle users, able to suggest viable alternatives to dislocation in urban environments, with reference to contextual information such as: street blockades , points of origin and destination and user preferences (avoid streets with uphill, downhill, high-speed roads, etc.), that is, from these contextual information how to suggest the best options for routes that meet these requirements. Someone suggests some algorithm or a combination of Algorithms that permit the inference of these User preferecias and then calculate what the possible route options?

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  What research have you done?  Have you done a literature search?  Have you found anything so far?

Comment: Hi, Examples of algorithms that found, refer to dijkstra algorithm and A*... but unfortunately they are not  context-aware :( 
Do you have something to suggest?